# Advantage of using checkstyle rather than using Eclipse built in code formatter?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

Is there any functional advantage of using checkstyle instead of Eclipse own code formatter? In either case, we would add some custom rules, but it would largely be based on Sun's java code convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some advantages for using *checkstyle*:

- portable between IDEs. If you decide to use *IntelliJ* later, or you have a team using a variety of IDEs, you still have a way to enforce consistency.
- better external tooling. It's much easier to integrate *checkstyle* with your external tools since it was really designed as a standalone framework. You can plug into your SCM as a pre-commit hook, or into your build tool, quite easily. Using *Eclipse* style convention you would need to write or locate a plugin to do the same thing.
- ability of creating your own rules. *Eclipse* defines a large set of styles, but checkstyle has more, and you can add your own custom rules.

The advantage of *Eclipse* formatter/styler, of course, is that it's already  built into the IDE, so if your team is already standardized on *Eclipse* you can get everyone up and running very quickly. But using *checkstyles* gives you more options.

Comment: Also Eclipse formatter doesn't show warnings - it can just silently format files. Your formatter will stay silent when someone has committed unreadable sources (without any formatting), but Checkstyle after check will show files with such warnings.